Is there a way to let me use my cell phone as a keyboard for my tablet?
I'm trying to use the Bluetooth keyboard app on my cell so I can control the use of my tablet.
Is it possible? Otherwise, is there a way to let me use my cell phone as a keyboard for my tablet?

Off-topic here. See: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+bluetooth+keyboard
